# Wordpress function is not called and ajax return 0

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, ajax, user-meta

I am developing a plugin called my-search-site and in that I have site links. If I click on the link, the jQuery function is called and that jQuery variable is passed to wordpress function from which It can be added to user meta.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
 $(".blavatar").click(function(){

        //toggle between the star icon 
        $(this).toggleClass('star-empty star_filled');
        //retrieve the clicked link's ID and it's href
        var fav_id =  $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        fav = $(this).parent().parent();
        //append favorites using ajax call

        jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: ajaxurl + "?action=fdiAddFavorite",
                data: {
                        action: 'fdiAddFavorite',
                        fav_id: fav_id,
                },
                success:function(data){
                $('#wp-admin-bar-my-favorite-list').append($(fav.html()));
                console.log(data);
                //console.log(fav_id);

                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                        alert(errorThrown);
                }

        //}).always(function() { alert("complete");
    });

        return false;
});
```

and on the same page my wordpress function is declared as below:

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_fdiAddFavorite', 'fdiAddFavorite');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fdiAddFavorite', 'fdiAddFavorite');

 function fdiAddFavorite() {
    $fav_id = get_post($_REQUEST['fav_id']);
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $favorite_list = get_user_meta($user_id, 'favorite links', true);
    //print_r($favorite_list);
    if(empty($favorite_list))
        $favorite_list = array();

    $favorite_list[] = $fav_id;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'favorite links', $favorite_list);
    //sort($favorite_list);
    //print_r($favorite_list);
    die('{"success": true}');
}
```

After click event the ajax returns 0 and the function is not called and can not be recognized by ajax call. I am not able to update the user meta. Can you please help me with it. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by your Ajax function being "on the same page"? What file do you declare that in? Remember that Ajax requests are a separate http request from the page you are making the requests from.

Comment: the ajax query and the function which is called by ajax are on the same page. I haven't make two different files for that.

Comment: How are you adding the javascript to your file?

Comment: Your Ajax function won't be loaded on the Ajax request because that is a different page- your Ajax function should be in a file that is loaded on *all* requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `url: ajaxurl + "?action=fdiAddFavorite",`, use two lines like this:

```
url: ajaxurl,
action: "fdiAddFavorite",
```

Then at the end of `fdiAddFavorite()`, you try something like this:

```
echo $favorite_list; // could also send message like "success!"
wp_die();
```